# Code unminify plugin for NetBeans IDE

Tags: css, code-formatting, netbeans-8, unminify

I want something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ that can work inside NetBeans IDE. I found a plugin that can minify the code but don't find any plugin to unminify the code. NetBeans "Format" command also does not work as I want.

I have CSS code which is written in 1 line like:

```
ul {margin:0;} ul li{margin:20px;}
```

I want to arrange it in multiple lines something like:

```
ul{
    margin:0;
}
li{
    margin:20px;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43263/jsbeautify , this is plugin inspired form [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) website